# Component is redirecting to its component itself in React.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am using react hooks with redux in my project. In the login component from my action file when I try to redirect to another page i.e. another component. It is redirecting to the login component within a few seconds.

Here is the code:
**authReducer.js**

```
const authReducer = (state = iState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "IS_LOGIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLogin: action.payload,
      };
    }
})
```

**userAction.js**

```
export const loginSubmit = (data, props) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}login`, data)
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.data.code == 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: "IS_LOGIN",
            payload: {
              data: result.data.data,
              authToken: result.data.authToken,
            },
          });

          localStorage.setItem("debateAccountToken", result.data.authToken);
          localStorage.setItem("email", result.data.data.email);
          localStorage.setItem("id", result.data.data.id);
          toast.success("Logged in successfully");

          // setInterval(() => {
          props.history.push("/log");
          // }, 3000);
        } else {
          toast.error("Email or password wrong!!");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error .. ", err);
        toast.error("Somethihng went wrong!!");
        setInterval(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        }, 3000);
      });
  };
};
```

**component file -> route of /log**

```
import React from "react";

function LoginPage() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

export default LoginPage;
```

**route file**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/UserLogin";
import Debate from "./components/debate/Debate";
import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage";
import UserRegister from "./components/UserRegister";
import LoginPage from "./components/LoginPage";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={UserRegister} />
          <Route exact path="/debate" component={Debate} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/log" component={LoginPage} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

From useraction it is redirecting to /log component but eventually it is returning back to login component too. Where might I be mistaken?

Comment: can you confirm that your catch block is not running ? Coz there i see window.location.reload(); after 3 seconds.

Comment: please share your router file .

Comment: @HadiPawar, no my catch block is not running.. As I said it is going to /log route and returning back to login component..

Comment: add exact to your `/login` and `/log` path

Comment: @VyasArpit, I added exact in route, but it is still doing the same.. nothing is changed

Comment: @JaynaTanawala try to replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. Also for debugging purposes I suggest to rename your `/log` to something that is not a prefix of another route.

Comment: @lavor, I have commented that setInterval code, though I am facing that issue. And I checked with changing route too. Nothing is changed.

Comment: I think there is maybe some problem in another part of code, you did not show us. Can you create minimal exaple in some sandbox?